# Insert data to table where select statement has more columns

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

Hello i would like to add some rows from my `pricelist` table to `products` table. I am trying to fill my `products` table by testing data. Is possible to make query where i can add random amount of rows to my `products` table? The main problem is that i have more rows in select statement than in insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO products(product_name, product_price)
SELECT name_product, price_product, IF(RAND() > 0.2,1,0) AS random
FROM pricelist
HAVING random = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your condition in the `WHERE` clause. Your calculated column `random` does not makes sense since you don't to insert it on the other table.

```
INSERT INTO products(product_name, product_price)
SELECT name_product, price_product
FROM pricelist
WHERE RAND() > 0.2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have more columns in select statement than in insert statement. The column number must match. There are also better ways to choose random rows...

```
INSERT INTO products(product_name, product_price)
SELECT name_product, price_product
FROM pricelist
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I meant what user '491243' wrote below.